# Dragging across lower part of reputation graph does exactly nothing in Google Chrome

Tags: bug

Just happened to check out someone's reputation graph and tried to select another period as per the instructions ("select an area by dragging across the lower chart"). In Google Chrome nothing happened. No change, no selection rectangle, nothing. Tried same in Internet Explorer and there it works as expected.

Not fussed about it, just thought I'd report it.

Versions

- Internet Explorer: 11.0.9600.17107
- Google Chrome: 34.0.1847.137 m (up-to-date according to its own about dialog)

Behavior persists even when:

- all installed Google Chrome extensions are disabled
- Google Chrome is restarted (extensions still disabled)
- Machine is restarted (extensions still disabled)

**Update**
I have duplicated this on a different machine. Completely different machine and running Win7 Pro instead of "Home".

Comment: working for me in chrome.  Do you have any add ins installed, like say NoScript?

Comment: What kind of time range are you selecting across?

Comment: @Oded: short ones, long ones, pure horizontal drag, diagonal drag, all sorts really. Basically left clicking and dragging the lower chart has no visible effect at all.

Comment: @Servy: yes I have add ins installed, but nothing like NoScript. I have Axure RP, Block from Analytics, DoNotTrack, Google Docs, HootSuite, Keep My Opt-Outs, LastPass and PostMan enabled. More installed but the ones I mentioned are the only ones that are enabled.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Does the problem persist if you temporarily disable all of those?

Comment: @Servy: yes it does. I disabled all extensions, opened a new tab, went to my own rep page. Dragging across the lower chart still has no effect. I'll try a restart of Google Chrome shortly (after I have finished reading a couple of tabs I currently have open).

Comment: Google Chrome restart didn't have any effect, @Servy, neither did rebooting my machine... (all extensions still disabled).

Comment: What is your zoom level set to? Not 100% I assume? This was already reported on MSE.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Wow. Psychic. You are 100% correct. Resetting the zoom level to 100% revived the time scale selection. And sorry, didn't think to check MSE (assume you mean meta.stackexchange.com?) Not used to having that yet... If you post it as an answer, I'll accept. Link to the issue on MSE would be nice :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an ancient issue that has never been fixed. It does not work correctly in Chrome at non default zoom level.

See [Select an area in rep graph not working on Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105061/select-an-area-in-rep-graph-not-working-on-chrome).

Even if it can't be fixed it would be nice if it detected the issue and told you the problem as the current behaviour is pretty confusing when you are affected by it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at normal (100%) zoom level now.

Comment: Works for me on default zoom level.