# The reputation graph area slider is broken

Tags: bug

[image]In the reputation tab, the "select an area by dragging across the lower chart" function appears to be broken.

On Windows 7, Chrome Version 51.0.2704.79, I cannot get it to slide to an earlier time frame.  This was working recently.

**Update:** I have provide a screenshot.  The area slider is not draggable.  When I hover over it, the pointer does not change to indicate I can drag.  It is stuck where you see it.

Comment: Windows 8.1, Chrome 51.0.2704.84 - cannot reproduce.

Comment: **Screenshot Please**, I can't  reproduce it in Win 7 Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 m.

Comment: No repo, same windows and Chrome as OP. Rodrigo, have you tried this without extensions enabled? Maybe one of yours is messing with it?

Comment: Thanks I did that same result.  Odd.

Comment: Hm same issue here? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255442/dragging-across-lower-part-of-reputation-graph-does-exactly-nothing-in-google-ch